# Windows Phone 8 app IsolatedStorageException / SecurityException on release built, NOT debug build

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app, using Sqlite, which works fine in debug build, but apparently is not locating files on release build.

A long stream of exceptions shows up on the console when running the app in release build.

Here is a snippit:

```
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

...and on and on.  Has anyone had any experience with these kind of exceptions popping up ONLY in a release build?  And, what would be the best approach to debugging this?  I am not even sure what part of my code is causing this?

For the sake of brevity, the details are all below:

It is clear that, among other things, my database file is not being located.  I have a sqlite database file stored locally in the app's directory, and when the app starts, it is copied to the local folder, and read and written to from there.  This worked with no problem in all the debug builds, but now, I am seeing logging errors (more on that below) of "Cannot open database file: " followed by the (heretofore correct) database file's path, and none of my UI elements which involve calls to the database are showing up.

I mentioned logging messages.  Obviously I am not getting console prints using System.Diagnostic.Debug in the release build but I have a logging system which writes to a file, which can be read in the app.

This seems to be working fine, and I can read it in the app fine.

Also, I initially had some errors pop up on the release build with SQLite, but those seemed to be from using old versions of the SQLite c# code, and cleared up after I followed these instructions: [A Workaround To Use SQLite In A Windows Phone 8 Application](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/workaround-use-sqlite-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You should run your Release build under the debugger and find out where the `SecurityException` is thrown from by changing the settings in the Debug>>Exceptions menu of Visual Studio.

That would at least allow you to find where this is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am a bit confused, how do I go about running the release build under the debugger?  I am trying to follow the steps outlined in ["How To Debug A Release Build"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz(v=vs.110).aspx) but I am not seeing the same thing it is describing in the project property page.  (I am using VS Express 2012 for Windows Phone by the way)

Comment: Just change the drop-down configuration combo-box in VS from Debug to Release and then hit F5. If you don't see this in VS Express you need to go into the VS options and switch on advanced mode or something like that.

Comment: Ah, I was not clear, I apologize.  Yes, I know how to build in release mode.  I thought by "debugger" you were referring to a different method of running the release build with more debugging options (such as system console prints) available or something.